# Vagrant up fails with ArgumentError

Tags: vagrant

I keep running into this strange error when I run the `vagrant up` command :

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb:163:in `=~': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

with the following Vagrant file. Here is my [Vagrant file](https://gist.github.com/achintangal/10990720) and the full [error
trace](https://gist.github.com/achintangal/10988684).  I tried using different versions of ruby and It hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Lastly, I am using version 1.5.1 of Vagrant and version 2.0.0p451 of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error with vagrant. I delete vagrant from my mac (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/installation/uninstallation.html), reinstall, and restart. I have 1.6.3. It happens every week it seems like.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I tried removing a non-ASCII character in the file path to the config file. Tyler from ClickOnTyler asked about special characters in my user name, which gave me the idea to try renaming the directory with my non-ASCII characters — “ ƒ” in this case. Now I no longer get that error, so I hope this solves your issue.

Now I have another error (that I will search for here rather than pollute thew thread.) I hope this helps.